# Direct sums of vector subspaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I'm struggling to show that if $W_{1},W_{2}$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $W_{1}+W_{2} = V$, then there exists a subspace $W_{3}$ of $W_{2}$ such that $V=W_{1}\oplus W_{3}$.

My idea was to remove from $W_{2}$ vectors in common with $W_{1}$, obtaining $W_{2}'$, in order to make their intersection the zero space. But now I'm having trouble showing that $W_{2}'$ is a subspace of $W_{2}$. Can you please help me?

Comment: The question is strange. If $W_1$ is a subspace of $V$, then there is $W_2$ s.t. $V=W_1 \oplus W_2$. In your question $W_2$ and $W_3$ are useless...

Comment: The question is not that every subspace is complemented. Rather that every supplement (i.e., subspace that sums with the original to the whole thing) contains a complement (i.e., subspace that *direct* sums with the original to the whole thing).

Comment: Regarding the actual question, removing the vectors from the intersection will not work, as the result is not a subspace. (Think removing a line from the plane.) If your spaces are finite-dimensional then you can do a sneaky induction. If not, you need to do some axiom of choice stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Choose a base $B_{W_1}=(c_1, c_2, ...)$ for $W_1$ and complete it to a base $B=(c_1, c_2, ..., d_1, d_2, ...)$ of $V$, then consider the projection of $V$ into $W_1$ given by $\psi(c_i)=c_i$, $\psi(d_i)=0$.

Clearly we have $V=\operatorname{im}\psi \bigoplus\ker\psi = W_1 \bigoplus\ker \psi$. $\ker\psi$ is the space you are looking for infact $\ker\psi \subseteq V - W_1 = W_2 - W_1 \subseteq W_2$ (leaving apart the trivial case $W_2 \subseteq W_1$).

Answer (score 1):

OK, since someone else has done it using bases, I will show the sleek way that works for finite-dimensional spaces.

Proceed by induction on $\dim(V)$, the result being clear if the dimension is $0$ or $1$.

If $W_2=V$ then one may choose any vector space complement to $V$. Thus just choose any basis for $W_1$ and extend to a basis for $V$. Then the last basis elements are a vector space complement.

If $W_2<V$ then by induction the result holds for $W_2$. Thus one may choose a complement $W_3$ to $W_1\cap W_2$ in $W_2$. Clearly $W_1\cap W_3=0$, and their dimensions sum to $\dim(V)$. Thus $W_3$ is the desired complement.